# Modification of a PHP url

Tags: php, variables, datetime

I am trying to create a series of buttons on a form which will update the page it is currently on.

The code for the buttons is in a include called Quicklinks and contains the below;

```
<input type=button 
value="Year to Date"
        onClick= "self.location='URL?start=2013-01-01&end=2013-12-31'">
<input type=button 
value="Previous Financial Quater"
        onClick= "self.location='URL?start=2013-06-01&end=2013-09-30'">
<input type=button 
value="Current Financial Quater"
        onClick= "self.location='URL?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-12-31'">
<input type=button 
value="Next Financial Quater"
        onClick= "self.location='URL?start=2014-01-01&end=2014-03-31'">
```

Basically I wanted to have the URL aspect of the above links to change dynamically based on what page is being shown to the user at the present time.

For example, if the user is looking at test.php and clicks the Current financial Quater buttom, I want it to place test.php into the url and navigate to :
    self.location='test.php?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-12-31

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want this all in the one include for the purposes of updating the dates each quarter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set window.location.search to the query string you want and it will reload the current page with the new query string:

```
<input type=button 
value="Year to Date"
        onClick= "window.location.search='?start=2013-01-01&end=2013-12-31'">
<input type=button 
value="Previous Financial Quater"
        onClick= "window.location.search='?start=2013-06-01&end=2013-09-30'">
<input type=button 
value="Current Financial Quater"
        onClick= "window.location.search='?start=2013-09-01&end=2013-12-31'">
<input type=button 
value="Next Financial Quater"
        onClick= "window.location.search='?start=2014-01-01&end=2014-03-31'">
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, works perfectly! Really appreciate your assistance!